# UITextField repositions itself when resigning responder

Tags: ios, ios6

My main controller is a `UITextFieldDelegate` and animates a `UITextField` when its editing status changes. In the storyboard the view's original position is in the centre of the screen (vertically and horizontally), when it is being edited I position it to the top of the screen. If I now complete the "Go" action from the keyboard, resign first responder on the text field, the text field pops back to its original position. I have tried retaining the frame of the text field in `textFieldShouldEndEditing`, but it continues to go back to its original position. How can I keep the view in the new position, even when the keyboard resigns?

I animate the view like this

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField isEqual: _toField] && !alreadyAnimated) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"editFieldAnimation" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2f];
        // move up to field
        CGRect textFieldFrame = [_toField frame];
        textFieldFrame.origin.y = 58; // default frame top margin
        _toField.frame = textFieldFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        alreadyAnimated = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: post your `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method and check out your autolayout constraints too.

Comment: This is probably an auto layout problem. You either need to turn it off, or animate your views using constraints rather than setting frames.

Comment: Thanks for the autolayout suggestions, I'll give those a shot in the morning!

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry for the late reply, you were correct that this was an auto layout issue. Animating the constraints was the solution. If you post as an answer I'll gladly accept.